# Posicionar elementos en forma de circulo CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicación-web, position

Estoy tratando de posicionar imágenes que están en un contenedor div en un HTML de manera que formen un circulo, algo mas grafico seria esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego quiero poder rotar estas imágenes con respecto al centro del div, dando la animación que giren alrededor del centro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes posicionar las imágenes usando las ecuaciones polares de una circunferencia y hacer la animación aumentando el ángulo cada cierto tiempo.

Dependiendo de la velocidad a la que quieres que rote puedes cambiar la variable `angulo` o el tiempo en el que quieres que se actualice con el `setInterval`. Dependiendo del número de imágenes que tengas y su separación modifica `n` y `r`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar:

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.element')

const n = 6;  // numero de circulos
const r = 120 // radio

let angulo = 0;
let originX = circles[0].offsetLeft
let originY = circles[0].offsetTop

setInterval(() => {
 angulo += 0.01
 circles.forEach((element,i) =>{
 element.style.left = `${originX + r*Math.cos(angulo + 2*Math.PI/n*i)}px`
 element.style.top = `${originY + r*Math.sin(angulo + 2*Math.PI/n*i)}px`})
},20)
```

```css
.element{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}

#circle{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height:340px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <div class='element' style="background:red"></div>
  <div class='element' style="background:green"></div>
  <div class='element' style="background:yellow"></div>
  <div class='element' style="background:orange"></div>
  <div class='element' style="background:blue"></div>
  <div class='element' style="background:salmon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Solución simple y elegante!

Comment: Muy buena lógica, una excelente solución

Comment: hla esta perfecto pero podrias decir como ponerlo en unhtml para cargarle las fotos y que giren graciassss